# Unable to see Lines of code in Size Metrics Widget for objectivec language

Tags: objective-c, sonarqube-scan

Currently on sonarqube 4.5.7 and are using sonar-objective-c (0.4.0) plugin to analyze the objectiveC code.We are able to successfully generate the oclint.xml depicting the static violation's present.

As of now, our git repo is having multiple language code and same are getting listed in Size Metrics widget

```
JavaScript  33,117

Java    31,441

XML     7,105

CSS     579

Python  68

Groovy  41
```

What anomaly I observed was that the Size Metrics Widget doesn't display info related to objectivec language.

Added below properties in the root level sonar-project.properties but no luck.

```
sonar.objectivec.project=RootFolder/subfolder/subfolder/Project.xcodeproj
sonar.objectivec.workspace=RootFolder/subfolder/subfolder/Project.xcworkspace
sonar.objectivec.appScheme=Project
```

Following link talks about additional properties to be set :
https://blog.octo.com/en/track-your-ios-application-code-quality-using-sonar/

- sonar.language=objc
- sonar.sources=Classes

But if I imbibe these 2 properties I will loose the existing multi language support which is present.Is there a way out in this case ?

Please guide.

Comment: Are you sure you have an analyzer for Objective-C installed?

Comment: Plugin @ /dir1/dir2/sonarqube-4.5.7/extensions/plugins/sonar-objective-c-plugin-0.4.0.jar

-->Scanner logs :
      Sensor Objective-C SurefireSensor done: 1 ms
      Sensor org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.coverage.CoberturaSensor@486ee396...
      Sensor org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.coverage.CoberturaSensor@486ee396 done: 8 ms
      Sensor org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.violations.OCLintSensor@1f4e8af1...
      Processing OCLint report /Folder1/Folder2/git/repo/oclint.xml
      Reporting 298 violations.
      Sensor org.sonar.plugins.objectivec.violations.OCLintSensor@1f4e8af1 done: 245 ms

Comment: As per my above snippet the violation's are getting detected. sonar.sources=. is set in my root sonar-project.properties. Is there a way to have objectivec lines of code in  Size Metrics widget ? Thanks..!!